# How to add a column in a table where I can put checkmarks in some cells for further processing?

Tags: sql, view, qt5, checkmark

I am using Qt5. 
Now I have a `QTableView` populated with data from a database table using `QSqlTableModel`. I added an extra column with `model->insertColumn(n);`.
I would like to be able - using the mouse - to put some checkmarks in some cells of this new added column, as - after exiting the `tableView` - I would need to do some further processing for the rows that are marked with the checkmark...
Is there a way of doing this? Please help.

BAD news is: I can add/change all cells in the table (using `model->setData(index, "...");` ), EXCEPT the cells of the newly added column...
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your QSqlTableModel is modifying (or trying to) the corresponding table in the database, and that's likely failing somehow. Is your extra column *really* corresponding to data coming from the database, or is it synthetized?

Anyhow, two possible solutions are

1. a proxy model in front of your original SQL model
2. subclass your SQL model

The idea is to use the proxy/subclass to augment the data (by synthetizing the extra column's data), as well as handle the checked status. In order to mark cells "checkable" you need to return `Qt::ItemIsCheckable` from your model's `flags()` implementation, then the view will call `data()` asking for the `Qt::CheckStateRole`.

Comment: No, the extra column is not coming from database, I just added it after a query, using "insertColumn()".     Thanks for the ideas, Peppe :)      I think I'll try the proxy model... never did that before, so I hope I will succeed, wish me luck! :)